# excluding KMZ layer in ogr2ogr PostGIS import

Tags: postgis, ogr2ogr, kmz

I'm trying to script the import of a KMZ file into my PostGIS 2.2.1 enabled PostgreSQL 9.5.1 database and am running into a problem where it's not importing all of the (several dozen) layers. I think it's because within the KMZ file, there's another KMZ file and it's tripping the import up. Below is the command, but my question is: is there a way to exclude certain layers/files within the KMZ during the import process?

```
ogr2ogr -overwrite -f "PostgreSQL" PG:"host='hostname' user=postgres dbname='databaseName' schemas=schemaName password=pw" -nln "tableName" "path\to\file\filename.kmz"
```

I see where you can select certain fields within each layer using the `-select` trigger, but is there something similar for entire layers?

here's what the unzipped kmz looks like in QGIS:

[image]

Comment: Unlikely that there's another KMZ inside the first KMZ.  You can check by unzipping the KMZ and inspecting it.

Comment: Could it be instead that one or more of the KML layers is actual an image, or a reference to an image service, and not an importable vector dataset?

Comment: unfortunately there's definitely another kmz inside the kmz. I'll add a picture to the question. These are vector lines that aren't being imported.

Comment: How does ogrinfo see the layers?

Comment: @user30184 `ogrinfo filename.kmz` displays the same layers (including the .kmz), just not in alphabetical order.

Comment: You should be able to include the layers that you want with a list `..."path\to\file\filename.kmz" "CHR Transmedia" "CHR Transmedia (#2)" "CHR Transmedia (#3)"`. I may be wrong and my syntax with the layer names may be wrong as well. Certainly some kind of quotes are needed because of spaces in layer names.